# Talking to the Last.fm API

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, last.fm

Working on a web app that talks to the last.fm API. For some reason, the ajax() function is not returning anything. Even though I see the app trying to talk with the API there's no callback, and even the "always" and "fail" functions fail to run. I've verified that the API key works fine. Not sure what's going on...

Here's the call, simplified for the purposes of this question:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {artist: 'cher', track: 'believe', method: "track.search", api_key: '(my key here)', format: 'json'},
done: function() {
  alert('done')
},
fail: function() {
  alert('fail')
},
always: function(data) {
     alert('always')
     try{
     var matches = data['results']['trackmatches']['track'][0]
     console.log(data)
     }
     catch(err) {
      returned = data['results']['opensearch:Query']['searchTerms']
      $('#album-display').find('ul').append(returned + "<br>")
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your console or network tab? Also, you'll need to use jsonp for remote ajax.

Comment: Yep, no errors in the console or network. Good point, can I simply change the datatype to 'jsonp'?

Comment: Not sure. Try it and see.

Comment: Tried, but still not working...

Comment: You said there aren't any errors on your network tab. Do you see the xhr request? What is the response?

Comment: Here's the response I see in the network tab: HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
X-Web-Node: www224
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Expires: Sat, 27 Jul 2013 18:20:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8;
Content-Encoding: gzip
Date: Fri, 26 Jul 2013 18:20:32 GMT
X-Varnish: 2205551160
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: close
X-cms: 1
X-varnish-host: varnish3